# do you know why my animate method doesnt work for top property?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've used animate property in my jquery file for top property but it's not working. Do you know what the reason is?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font awsome/FontAwesome.Pro.5.11.2.Web/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="font awsome/FontAwesome.Pro.5.11.2.Web/js/all.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class=" top-back">
        <img src="images/Untitled-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class=" main-back" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 ">

                            <div class="blue">
                                <img class="magic" src="images/magic.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: 4.5%;">
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="left: 25%; top: 5px" class="pics1"><img src="images/face1.png" alt="" >Facelift surgery</li>
                                    <li style="left: 25%; top: 200px" class="pics2"><img src="images/face2.png" alt="">Lip Augmentation</li>
                                    <li style="left: 25%; top: 390px" class="pics3"><img src="images/face3.png" alt="">Botox Injections</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="row white-box">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="">
                            <h1>Facelift Surgery</h1>
                            <p>Aromatherapy has a very beneficial effect on the human body and promotes maximum relaxation. The use of aroma oils in the process of massage enhances its effect, relieves fatigue.

                            </p>
                            <button>Make an appointment</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-7 face">
                            <img src="images/face.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-back">
        <img src="images/Untitled-3.png" alt="">
    </div>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* CSS Document */
body{
    margin: 0
}
.top-back img{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 !important;
 position: relative;
 top: 10px
}
.main-back{
    background-color: #f3e5d8;
    height: 600px
}
.bottom-back img{
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%
}
.white-box{
    background-color: #fff9f3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 108px;
    height: 450px
}
.face img{
    width: 94.5%;;
    position: absolute;
    top: -124px;
    right: 23px;
}
.blue{

    background-color:#2d3663;

    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    width: 78%
}
.blue ul{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 596px

}
.blue li{
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute

}
.blue img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
.white-box h1 {
    color: #cd8274;
    margin-top: 40px
}
.white-box p{
    color: #474e75;
    margin: 40px 0;
    line-height: 29px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pics2').hover(function(){
        $('.magic').animate({top: "195px"});

    });
    $('.pics1').hover(function(){
        $('.magic').animate({top: "0"});


    });
    $('.pics3').hover(function(){
        $('.magic').animate({top: "384px"});

    })

});// JavaScript Document`
```

Answer (score 1):

i finally found the reason... the CDN of jquery must not be the first one. i changed the position of that and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Console shows me ***$(...).animate is not a function***

This is the reason

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Remove it and everything will work. This version of jQuery **jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js** is shorter (slim) and doesn't support **animate** function.

Use the full one instead.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```